# How to create a trade route?

Tags: civilization-6

I build a trader and click on it. The cities that I can trade with light up in green. But I can't figure out how to actually create the trade route. Right clicking on the destination green area doesn't work, nor does it work when I right click on the city name.

Answer (score 5):

You have to click on the city you chose, and then on the button on top of the possible trade routes:

[image]